# prepositions at / of

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct:

The Faculty of History **at** Jagiellonian University

or

The Faculty of History **of** Jagiellonian University

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences can be correct depending on how you use them.

The first sentence uses **at** to give a location.
In the second sentence **of** is used to show belonging or connection.
(the faculty belongs to that university and no other).

We can show these uses in the following questions and answers below:

**Question:** Where can I find the faculty of History?
**Answer**:   You can find the Faculty of History at Jagiellanian University**.=location**

**Question**: Where is the best University to study History in this country?
**Answer**: You can study History at the faculty of History **of** Jagiellanian University. (Notice that here you use at to show location of the faculty, but you use **for** to show that the faculty is connected to ,or belongs to Jagiellanian University (and no other University).

I hope that helps

Comment: Helps indeed, thx ;)